# How to upgrade/swap subscriptions when using subscription taxes with Laravel Cashier

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

Laravel Cashier makes it pretty simple to create subscriptions with subscription taxes, but I have found that when it comes to swapping subscriptions, it can't deal with taxes in that context.

Have you ran into this issue? How did you go about addressing it?

Comment: Same problem here dude. Have you find a solution to this?

Comment: Honestly, it's been so long that I don't know anymore. I think I ended up finding an alternate solution, so feel free to check out some of my other questions / answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, it might be a bit late but it should help others.

So you need to override the Laravel\Cashier\Billable::invoice() method on your User (or any Billable) model to take the `"tax_percent" => $this->taxPercentage()`. In other words add the following piece of code to your User (or any other billable) model class.

```
public function invoice()
{
    if ($this->stripe_id) {
        try {
            return StripeInvoice::create(['customer' => $this->stripe_id, "tax_percent" => $this->taxPercentage()], $this->getStripeKey())->pay();
        } catch (StripeErrorInvalidRequest $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Also remember to add this new requirements to your class

```
use Stripe\Invoice as StripeInvoice;
use Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest as StripeErrorInvalidRequest;
```